# Keeping Navigation Menu Fixed at Top of Page (Weebly)

Tags: css, weebly

I have a website on Weebly where the template causes the navigation menu to follow you as you scroll down, making it visible wherever you are on the page. The navigation menu is getting in the way of my content, so it would be great if I could just keep it at the top of the page.

I'm trying to paste the code on here, but it's not properly formatting, so I'll post an image of it:

```css
/* Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.nav {
    padding: 0 0 0 20px !important;
}
.nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    padding:8px 15px;
    height:23px;
}
.nav ul li#active,
.nav ul li:hover {
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:6px 13px;
}
.nav ul li a {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:23px;
}
#nav-wrap .container ul li#active a,
#nav-wrap .container ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none !important;
    border: 0;
}
.landing-page:before,
.splash-page:before,
.tall-header-page:before,
.short-header-page:before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent url(‘menu-bg.png‘) left top repeat;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell without seeing the matching HTML but I believe removing `position: fixed` from the selectors at the bottom of the page will solve your problem.

You can format code by adding four spaces before each line, this is easy to do: select everything in notepad and press tab.